# arduino java serial communication not working

Tags: java, arduino, communication

I'm trying to communicate from my arduino to java using eclipse. I am using this tutorial [arduino -> java](http://playground.arduino.cc/interfacing/java) the only problem is i get a message "could not find com port" and i dont know how to fix this. I think it has to do with me not chosing the right port in the code.

[Sceenshot](http://s25.postimg.org/d424zdqlr/Naamloos.png)

Here you can see the message i get from eclipse and that the arduino is using com 3 and the serial communication is working.

I might have this wrong but the java code is supposed to get the string "Hello world" and display it in the console right ?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following arduino example ,it very easy to get the hello world message in your console .you just need to correctly set the serial port and have the `rxtx` library in your java project.

#### if you don't know the com port your arduino is using ,goto your arduino editor and goto tool->port and set a com port to it . and add the same port in your java code

if you are in windows then your `PORT_NAMES[]` array should look like bellow.

`private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = { "COM3"};`

for your case it may be `COM3` ,`COM4`, `COM6`, or any other port ,just set the right one.

#### and ofcourse connect your arduino first.